# ASP.NET Identity's UserManager caches users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, unity-container

We're using ASP.NET Identity 2.2 with ASP.NET MVC 5.2, Entity Framework 6.2 and Unity 5.7.

We have a class, `ConnectUserManager`, that derives from ASP.NET Identity's `UserManager`. A newly constructed `UserStore` is passed to `UserManager` every time.

The lifetime of `ConnectUserManager` (and thus of `UserManager`) is per request:

```
Container.RegisterType<ConnectUserManager>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        Container.Resolve<ConnectDbContext>(),
        Container.Resolve<ITemplateManager>(),
        Settings.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout,
        Settings.AccountLockoutTimeSpan));
```

When we need to display the details for a given user, a controller action retrieves the user as such:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    ...
}
```

where `UserManager` is an injected property:

```
[Dependency]
public ConnectUserManager UserManager { get; set; }
```

**The problem is that `user` appears to come from a cache**: modifications in the database don't appear to have any effect on what our application displays.

This code has been in production for a year and we never had any issue with it: the cache seems properly invalidated when *our code* modifies a user.

We only noticed the problem now because when Identity locks a user out, it updates the user's `LockoutEndDateUtc` property but seemingly without invalidating the cache, and we get a stale `LockoutEndDateUtc` value in our display.

What are we doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

@DotNetMatt linked the following question in a comment:
[Entity Framework caching in aspnet Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041352/entity-framework-caching-in-aspnet-identity).

Unless I'm missing something, the accepted solution (at the time of writing anyway) seems completely unrelated to the original poster's and to my problem.

However, the original poster seems to have found the (a?) solution by himself: "What I did was implemented my own userstore and manually accessed EF and used .AsNoTracking() to avoid the caching."

Is there any way to do this without having to reimplement (or subclass) the user store?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework caching in aspnet Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041352/entity-framework-caching-in-aspnet-identity)

Comment: @DotNetMatt While that link is very interesting (and I must admit I hadn't found it), I think it's a different problem.

Comment: @DotNetMatt Regarding the question you linked to: The accepted answer is really unrelated to the problem the original poster and I are having, but we seem to indeed both have the same problem. It appears the original poster found the right answer by himself (see Edit 2 of his question).

Comment: after reading your answer below, indeed it is a separate problem. Glad you could find a solution, and that you shared it with the community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. @trailmax was correct (in comments to his own answer) that I had captive dependencies lying around.

The bug was actually in the snippet of code from my question that configures injection of `ConnectUserManager` dependencies:

```
Container.RegisterType<ConnectUserManager>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        Container.Resolve<ConnectDbContext>(),
        Container.Resolve<ITemplateManager>(),
        Settings.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout,
        Settings.AccountLockoutTimeSpan));
```

This resolves `ConnectDbContext` dependencies **once**, here and now, unlike the following version:

```
Container.RegisterType<ConnectUserManager>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory(
        container => new ConnectUserManager(
            container.Resolve<ConnectDbContext>(),
            container.Resolve<ITemplateManager>(),
            Settings.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout,
            Settings.AccountLockoutTimeSpan)));
```

which correctly resolves dependencies **every time** a new `ConnectUserManager` is constructed.

Comment: So there was lifetime scope issue after all!

Comment: There was! After a while I realized that EF's caching was really only possible if a DB context was shared somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is EF fluke. Identity does not have any inbuilt caching.
I suspect your lifetimescope for `ConnectDbContext` is per depedency, not per request.

So what happens is once instance of `ConnectDbContext` returns you with instance o `ApplicationUser`. Then another instance of `ConnectDbContext` does the lockout. But then when you go back to the first instance of `ConnectDbContext`, it does not know anything about the update that has been done by something else. Hence when you get the same instance second time, it does not go into the database, it returns you already tracked instance of this user.

Way to fix this - make sure your lifetime scopes match for all the moving parts involved: `ConnectUserManager`,`UserStore` and `ConnectDbContext`. So whenever you get objects form DB, it is always the same instance of `ConnectDbContext` that is providing this for you.

Also the answer you link to - see the very last comment, OP says he has the same scoping issue.

Comment: On the contrary, a new instance of `ConnectDbContext` is created everytime: `Container.RegisterType<ConnectDbContext>();`

Comment: In other words, it is scoped per dependency. This is your problem. It should be scoped per request.

Comment: Oh, really. Now that's interesting! I'm concerned about the unintended consequences of changing the DB context's lifetime though.

Comment: [DbContext should be scoped per request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588594/809357). It will possibly fix your other issues that you don't know about yet.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the lifetime of the DbContext to be per-request instead of per injection doesn't appear to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are working with the same instance of dbcontxt? It is possible that you have a captive dependency somewhere that prevents you from having a desired lifetime scope

Comment: Most of our uses of `DbContext` are very transient, we create them and dispose them immediately (with `using`). We don't need and don't rely on entities being still attached to their context. I guess that's why changing the lifetime of `DbContext` didn't change anything.

Comment: In that case I don't see an easy solution other than rewriting `UserStore` to add `.AsNoTracking()` all over the place.

Comment: Or you can have a look on alternative DB storage providers for Identity like [Asp.Net.Identity.Dapper](https://github.com/whisperdancer/AspNet.Identity.Dapper) and get away from EF for Identity purposes.

Comment: Your suggestion of rewriting `UserStore` using `AsNoTracking()` seems to indicate to me that there is a fundamental limitation in Identity's EF-based user store in that it does *not* support external modifications to the database, in which case the issue really has nothing to do with `DbContext`. Would you consider that statement correct?

Comment: Nope, I would apply that statement to EF rather than to Identity. This is all EF issue, not Identity.

Comment: Out of interest, can you try this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615276/809357 I would not recommend using it all the time, as this will cause issues with using EF, but worth a test

Comment: Sure, the problem is general in the sense that it's EF doing the caching, but Identity's `UserStore` not using `AsNoTracking()` could be considered a limitation of Identity ("Identity's user store does not force-disable caching"). Anyway I get your point. FWIW disabling `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` does not fix the problem either.

Comment: I think you may be right when you say "It is possible that you have a captive dependency somewhere that prevents you from having a desired lifetime scope." I don't see how entities can be cached when a new `DbContext` is created at every request (or at every dependency injection).